# LinearLayout add view with animation

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I am adding view to linearlayout, when i add views the the previous view get shifted. But what i want is that the shifiting of views is done with animation. Please help.

Comment: Flipper - http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using View Flipper , try this [Link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/viewflipper-animation.html)